# mySQL statement in <script> tags

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have loads of mySQL statements in my (WordPress) website and they all work fine. I now have the need to execute an additional mySQL statement within the OnClick event of a button. I have the OnClick event handler and a simple Alert statement shows that the event fires and I can access the variable I need. However if I put the mySQL statement into the script tag where the event handler is it fails (nothing happens, not even the Alert). 
Obviously the problem is with trying to combine HTML, PHP, JavaScript and mySQL in one line of code!
It's all a bit beyond me I'm afraid, hopefully someone can point out how I should be doing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
  alert("DELETE from 'position' where id=" + $poid);
  <?php echo $mydb->query($mydb->prepare("DELETE from 'position' where id=%d",$poid)); ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: That PHP will run when the PHP is **generating** the JavaScript, not when the JS function is called.

Comment: Your PHP code can't run in a browser. It has to run in the backend server. What you can do is, develop a POST handler in your PHP code. From onClick event, call the POST api with the values that you need. And inside the code execute the DB script.

Comment: Feel free to ask me questions if you need any clarification

Comment: Thank you both Quentin and shakhawat. I'm not sure I really understand the answer but I trust you both! I will have a go at re-writing the page using POST (I know that works - it's just very inelegant in this situation).